# Why does 安否 ("peaceful" + "negate") combine to mean "safety"?

Tags: kanji, etymology

Breaking the Kanji from down 安否 into their constituent meanings:

- **安:** content, peaceful, quiet
- **否:** negate

**Question:** Why would combining (e.g.) "peaceful" with "negate" result in a meaning of "safety", when it seems like it could be ascribed the opposite meaning? Is there some etymological reason for this that might make it easier to remember?

Comment: You should check [how 安否 is used in real sentences](https://yourei.jp/%E5%AE%89%E5%90%A6). You can check, inquire, know or worry about one's 安否, but you cannot assure or improve one's 安否.

Comment: Or you might try a monolingual dictionary. This [one](https://www.weblio.jp/content/安否) says 無事かどうかということ. I’m rather shocked to learn bilingual dictionaries just say “safety”.

Comment: Sadly, [無事 itself is defined simply as "safety"](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%84%A1%E4%BA%8B)... 無事 and 安否 are words used only when someone is/was thought to be in danger after something bad happened.

Comment: FYI Japanese has words that combine a kanji having a certain meaning with another kanji having the opposite. 安否 is one, many others exist like 開閉 高低 明暗 男女 老若 是非 有無 大小 and so on...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is more like *or not*. The following dictionary entry explicitly gives the usage:

> [否](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/kanji/%E5%90%A6/#jn-182283)
>
> ２ …か…でないか。「安否・可否・合否・採否・賛否・実否・真否・正否・成否・存否・諾否・適否・当否・認否・能否・良否」

安否=safe or not, 可否=possible or not, 合否=(about exams) passed or not, etc.